# Check if file/blob object is valid UTF-8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, utf

I need a function that can check if a file or blob object is valid UTF-8. I can get the text and check for � characters, but if the string has that character to begin with, the function would mark it as invalid.

```js
function isUTF8(blob) {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    const text = await blob.text();
    resolve(!~text.indexOf("�"));
  });
}

// "�" is valid utf-8 but the function returns false
isUTF8(new Blob(["�"])).then(console.log);

// returns true
isUTF8(new Blob(["example"])).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) API:

```js
async function isUTF8(blob) {
  const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8', { fatal: true });
  const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  try {
    decoder.decode(buffer);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError)
      return false;
    throw e;
  }
  return true;
}

(async () => {

console.log(await isUTF8(new Blob(
  [new Uint8Array([0x80])]))); // false
console.log(await isUTF8(new Blob(
  [new Uint8Array([0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd])]))); // true
console.log(await isUTF8(new Blob(
  ["\ufffd"]))); // true
console.log(await isUTF8(new Blob(
  ["example"]))); // true

})().catch(e => console.warn(e));
```

The above loads the entire `Blob` into an `ArrayBuffer` for simplicity.  If memory-efficiency becomes an issue, you may look into using the `.stream()` method to process the `Blob` in parts, without holding it in memory in its entirety.

Comment: Just a note regarding the last sentence: using the `.decode(buf, { stream })` option, it becomes very important to set the `stream` option to `false` when processing the last chunk (usually it's not necessary, but `fatal` would ignore some surrogates otherwise.